# have child elements inherate parents font size

Tags: css

I have a parent div that has a class style with font-size:11px. I want all children elements to have the same font size. The problem is some of the elements are p tags that are already styled with a larger font. I thought if the parent would rule but I guess not. Any ideas on how I can make the parent rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/QZjBV/

You don't need to use any additional classes/ID's or use !important to do what you are after.

Comment: That jsfiddle page is gone. Anyone care to explain what was proposed here?

Answer (score 2):

```
parent *{
    font-size:inherit!important;
}
```

Comment: This isn't great advice at all... Using !important is a lazy solution that could cause problems down the track.

Comment: @joshuanhibbert Well yes, but it means you won't have to make sure you have an extra style rule for every possible styled element that could be a child.

Comment: Font sizing should be consistent across a website so the amount of additional rules needing to be written should be minimal.